# Регулярное выражение для имени с дополнительными условиями

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Нужно регулярное выражение которое будет описывать имя на латинице или кириллице но с некоторыми нюансами. В имени может присутствовать пробел, ' и - , но самостоятельно без букв они быть не могут и не могут быть в начале и конце строки.
Написал такую регулярку:

> ([A-Za-zА-Яа-я-\'\s]+)

но она не исключает возможность ввести только символы, что нельзя.
Как написать правильное выражение?

Comment: `самостоятельно без букв они быть не могут` а как разделяются другие слова? приведите несколько строк, в которых находится искомое

Comment: Иван Иванович, Иван-Иванович, И'ван Иванович, Иван - правильно
- или '- или пробел - не правильно

Comment: ([A-Za-zА-Яа-я]{1}[A-Za-zА-Яа-я-\'\s]*)

Comment: спасибо, почти то что нужно, а возможно сделать еще запрет на начало и конец строки с символа или пробела?

Comment: (^[A-Za-zА-Яа-я]{1}[A-Za-zА-Яа-я-\'\s]*[A-Za-zА-Яа-я]{1}$)

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю

```
/^[A-Za-zА-Яа-яёЁ]+(?:[-'\s][A-Za-zА-Яа-яёЁ]+)*$/
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/go3AXQ/1/).

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `[A-Za-zА-Яа-яёЁ]+` - 1 и более английских и русских букв
- `(?:` - начало незахватывающей группы

  - `[-'\s]` - 1 дефис, апостроф или пробельный символ
  - `[A-Za-zА-Яа-яёЁ]+` - 1 и более английских и русских букв
- `)*` - повтор 0 и более раз
- `$` - конец строки.

```js
var strs = ["Иван Иванович","Иван-Иванович","И'ван Иванович","Иван","Иван'-Иванович","-Иван-Иванович","Иван-Иванович-","Иван-Иванович'"];
var re = /^[A-Za-zА-Яа-яёЁ]+(?:[-'\s][A-Za-zА-Яа-яёЁ]+)*$/;
for (var s of strs) {
  console.log(s,"=>",re.test(s));
}
```